# How does Spark SQL optimize joins? What are the optimization tricks?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand how spark 2.0 works for DataFrame API
Being a DataFrame, spark has knowledge about the structure of the data.

1. When joining big table to small  table I understand that broadcasting the smaller table is a good idea
2. However when joining big table to big table , what optimization tricks are there? Does sorting help ? Or would spark do the sorting internally? When should I repartition the data?

Any explanations would help

Answer (score 2):

**DISCLAIMER**: I'm still a newbie in this area of optimizing join queries so take it with a grain of salt.

---

Spark SQL comes with [JoinSelection](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala#L112) execution planning strategy that translates a logical join to one of the supported join physical operators (per join physical operator selection requirements).

There are 6 different types of physical join operators:

1. `BroadcastHashJoinExec` when left or right join side can be broadcast (i.e. smaller than `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` which is `10M` by default)
2. `ShuffledHashJoinExec` when `spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin` is disabled and it's possible to build hash maps for left or right join side (among the requirements)
3. `SortMergeJoinExec` when left join keys are "orderable"
4. `BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec` when there are no joining keys and left or right join side could be broadcast
5. `CartesianProductExec` when it's inner or cross join with no join condition
6. `BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec` when no other have matched

As you can see there's a lot of theory to digest to *"what optimization tricks are there"*.

> Does sorting help ?

Yes. See `SortMergeJoinExec` operator.

> Or would spark do the sorting internally?

It will try, but humans can (still?) do wonders.

> When should I repartition the data?

Always if you can and know that pruning can help. That can reduce the number of rows to deal with and effectively allows for `BroadcastHashJoinExec` over `ShuffledHashJoinExec` or the others.

I also think that repartitioning the data can be of particular help with cost-based optimization where table pruning could reduce the number of columns and rows, and in turn the table size and the cost of one join over others in general.